# MySQL : Select on timestamp column, change seconds to 00 and round minutes down to nearest 10

Tags: mysql, timestamp, rounding, minute

I have a table with a timestamp column as this:

2013-04-05 22:33:50

2013-04-05 22:42:03

2013-04-05 22:42:03

I want to make a SELECT on it and receive results with seconds 00 and minutes rounded down to nearest 10. As:

2013-04-05 22:30:00

2013-04-05 22:40:00

2013-04-05 22:40:00

How is this done? 
I cannot update or insert on the table, only select.

Comment: @DanyCaissy That would be an inefficient way to do this simple SQL task.

Comment: @RyanKempt who is DanyCaissy? Was there another reply that was deleted?

Comment: Yes, apparently the comment was deleted, the user had suggested using a server side language such as PHP to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(ticktick, INTERVAL MOD(MINUTE(ticktick),10) MINUTE), INTERVAL SECOND(ticktick) SECOND) FROM `table`
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks!  Is there a way in a query like this to alias the table name to something else, so as not to have to write it out 3 times?